# Interpreting coefficients for multinomial regression with >2 classes?

Tags: r, multinomial-logit

In `R`, I am fitting a model using the `multinom()` function from the `nnet` package. There is only 1 response variable and there are >2 classes. When I have a model with >3 classes, there's an error that says there are too many weights, so I'm using 3 classes: 0, 1, and 2 (categorical variables). The output from `multinom()` is stored in `model`.

Before, when I used 2 classes, `summary(model)$coefficients` returned a vector of numeric coefficients. When I used 3 classes, `summary(model)$coefficients` returned a matrix with two rows of coefficients: one for class '1' and one for class '2'. So I'm looking to learn how multinomial logistic regression works. Why do class 1 and 2 have separate sets of coefficients? Does it run logistic regression using class 0 vs 1 and for class 1 vs 2? What about class 0 vs 2? If it compares them all, where are the coefficients for all 3C2 comparisons, instead of just for 2 comparisons?

Comment: Since this is about interpreting the coefficients, rather than getting the code to run, I think it might be on-topic here.

Comment: It would help if you could paste in your output & be more specific regarding what you need help interpreting. As it is, I think you just need a general overview of multinomial logistic regression.

Comment: I think you will find the information you need in the linked thread. Please 
read it. If it isn't what you want / you still have a question afterwards, 
come back here & edit your question to state what you learned & what you still 
need to know. Then we can provide the information you need without just 
duplicating material elsewhere that already didn't help you.

Answer (score 5):

Basically, [logistic regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression) works in terms of log odds of one class ("success") given another ("failure") that servers as a "default" class and translates them to probability using inverse of logit function. [Multinomial regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_logistic_regression) is an extension of logistic regression to case of $K>2$ classes. It works in terms of log odds of some class given some other "default" class. This means that when using multinomial regression we focus on pairwise relations with the "default" class. So for $K$ classes we need $K-1$ sets of linear predictors, since we are looking at $K-1$ comparisons between classes. Yes, this means that we are ignoring other pairwise relations and assume that they are irrelevant given the relation with the "default" class.