# Logistic Regression?

Tags: regression, logistic, multinomial-logit

Can you use logistic regression if you have more than two options for the dependent variable. Instead of just a yes/no option I could have more than 2 options. I have 20+ predictor variables.

Comment: Yes you can! Google for multinomial logistic regression.

Comment: @ilanman It's possible, but I expect that the OP meant exactly what the question said.

Comment: @Alex is your response ordered categories (e.g. high, medium, low) or nominal categories (red, blue, yellow)?

Comment: Glen_b♦ my response would be nominal

Answer (score 3):

If you have more then two categories it's not logistic regression, but [multinomial logistic regression (also known as multinomial regression)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_logistic_regression). While logistic regression model is defined in terms of conditional odds of one category as compared to another, in multinomial model you [compare $K-1$ categories to the $K$th category](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/261567/interpreting-coefficients-for-multinomial-regression-with-2-classes/261668#261668) that serves as a "default" category. If your categories are ordered, you will use [ordinal regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_regression), that is a similar model but for ordered categories.

See the [Interpreting exp(B) in multinomial logistic regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17196/interpreting-expb-in-multinomial-logistic-regression) thread for extended discussion of multinomial model.

Comment: Just to correct what Tim indicated, with more than two categorical variables it is actually Multinomial Logistic Regression not Multinomial Regression as confirmed by Tim's own reference at Wikipedia.

Comment: @Sympa the name "multinomial regression" is also used, you can easily google it.

Comment: Tim couldn't one advance that Logistic Regression works just fine with more than two variables.  And, that in such situation it is called either Multinomial Regression or Multinomial Logistic Regression.