# How to have a "None of the above" category in a Logistic Regression?

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, linear-model, outliers, supervised-learning

I have a [Logistic Regression](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html) supervised classifier that is trained on `n=365 observations` and `m=179 attributes` with `c=5 classes`.  It's performing at 94.9% accuracy using a very robust cross-validation procedure.  The model naively assumes that each of the new observations will fall into one of those categories but there may be an instance where there is a completely unknown class.  **Is there a way to model a `None of the above` category?** I was going to look at the probabilities but the probabilities are very high for predictions even if the model predicted it incorrectly.

Comment: How can it "*be an instance where there is a completely unknown class*" if the representation of the world the model trains upon must always have 5 classes? You might want to consider creating artificial noise examples but that's another ball game... (In general +1 at Tim's answer and comment, they are pointing you to the correct direction.)

Comment: First, follow the advice from @Tim. Second, you may need to be more skeptical of your model. With so few cases and even with only 2 classes in logistic regression, your model should usually only consider about 10-20 features as predictors unless you are penalizing as with ridge regression. You may be overfit and have a model that doesn't apply well to new data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, you are talking about [multinomial regression, not logistic regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/269438/logistic-regression/269440#269440). Second, neither logistic regression nor multinomial regression [are classifiers](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/127042/why-isnt-logistic-regression-called-logistic-classification/127044#127044). Logistic regression and multinomial regression both predict probabilities of belonging to some class. To make a classifier of them you need a decision rule (if probability is greater then *some value*, classify this as *some class*).

It is up to you to define the decision rule. You are free to decide that if the probability of belonging to any class is not greater then *some value*, neither of the categories can be chosen.

Comment: Thanks for this.  The implementation I'm using has a `one-vs-rest` option.  Does that make it an ensemble of logistic regressions or is it still considered a multinomial regression?

Comment: @O.rka In such case it's an ensemble. Still, my answer applies as you can use such approach with any method that returns probabilistic "classifications".

Answer (score 3):

No way, you either have some of the non-class data already and set them into a 6th class and train the model with the 6th class. Or you set some thresholds for scoring the likeliness that a sample falls into each class evaluated by something like hidden markov model, but the accuracy would be worse than machine learning models. And as you don't even have non-class data now, you can't really have a fair classifier that can distinguish the true non-class data.